# Ubuntu 12.04 lts graphic problem

Tags: graphics, compiz

i'm using Ubuntu 12.04 lts , 
i installed compiz and after some day i uninstalled it 
but after unistalling something bad has happened

my graphic now is something like this :

[image]

what can i do to make it like before?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is compositing is disabled, which means you won't get effects like transparency and shadow. Try reinstalling compiz-config and search for compositing, and enable it.

Comment: Sorry it's hard to add detail on my non-smartphone, I'll try to add more detail later ;)